# Can't get a SceneManagement script to work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a script to work where I have a button that, when I click, loads a scene called PlayScene that I load smaller ScenarioScenes on top of, via PlayScene, to make levels. I've read through the SceneManagement and Button documentation, but I can't get it to work, and it just throws CS1002 at 19,21.

My unity version is 2019.3.11f1.

The script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class playButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button play;
    void Update()
    {
        play.onClick{SceneManager.LoadScene("PlayScene", LoadSceneMode.Single);};
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s not valid c# code

Comment: which one is the 19th line? `play.onClick?`

Comment: yes it is, i should've been more specific

Comment: You must set `public Button play` button from Unity Editor by dragging and dropping the GameObject into the PlayButton component

Comment: I am attaching this TO the button, not the EventSystem because that's how I decided to do it and it might break everything which i'm not trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments in the question, you said that you already assign the button. So the only thing left is to fix your onClick listener.

```
play.onClick.AddListener(()=>{SceneManager.LoadScene("PlayScene", LoadSceneMode.Single);});
```